# If scrollTop is greater than value, then do this ONLY ONCE

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user scrolls past 10px from the top, I'd like to hijack their scroll and scroll them down to certain div. After this happens once, I'd like to release the scroll to be free to scroll wherever. How do I do this?

My current code works but it won't let user to scroll freely after that initial scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    //if I scroll more than 1000px...
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 10){
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('#main').offset().top}, 900, function(){
            h = 2; 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: whats the h = 2 for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    //if I scroll more than 1000px...
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 10 && scrolled == false){
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('#main').offset().top}, 900, function(){
            h = 2; 
        });
      scrolled = true;
    } else if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      scrolled = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That works. How would I reset the value back to false if user returns to the very top of the page? Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying this but it doesn't seem to make the animation run again: 'if ($(document).scrollTop() < 10) {
        var scrolled = false;
    }'

Comment: Tried that. it's running the scroll animation again.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with your suggested code. Again- it works the first time but doesn't seem to reset the variable back to false. http://jsfiddle.net/beliy333/phyes2v7/2/

Comment: Sorry I have forget if($(window).scrollTop() == 0), I have updated code it will work now @user1389082

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your time!